# ClassNotFoundException: after obfuscation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, obfuscation

I am creating a library. My library has method for open another activity

```
val ACTION: String
    get() = "org.comp.sign.Auth"

    internal fun createIntent(input: Pair<AuthorizationParams, Config>): Intent {
        return Intent(ACTION).apply {
            val loggingData = input.first.parseToPair()
            putExtra(PARAMS_TYPE, loggingData.first)
            putExtra(PARAMS_FIELD, loggingData.second)
            putExtra(CONFIG_DATA, input.second.toData())
        }
    }
```

I used to intent-filter cause I would like to do obfuscation in my code, if was opening it without
intent-filter my Activity class would not be obfuscation

library's manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".config.internal.ui.view.CompActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Auth">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.comp.sign.Auth" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

when i implementation my lib in another project i throw a exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.comp.sign.auth.a.a.d.a.a
```

Project was finding Activity class, but it has different name

If I used to save class with the proguard rule `-keep class !org.comp.sign.auth.config.internal.ui.view.CompActivity`

then in my library will be many another files that disappeared when obfuscation

If there is a way around this?

Sorry for my English